# Why does water flowing from a 'flat' nozzle (slit) become thinner and again wider as it flows down

Tags: fluid-dynamics

It's very clear why the water gets thinner as it gets down. But in this picture attached, where the faucet nozzle is a flat slit, I do observe the water gets thinner and again wider after some point (making some 'X' shape) and further more I barely see the water flow has spun (rotated) a little. I don't know if this picture is photoshopped though. How can we solve this phenomenon. I have observed this phenomenon a little differently in my childhood when watering the trees using the garden horse while pressing the mouth of the horse by thumb and making the water out space thinner (flat and thin) so that water is sprayed furthest and the water goes like a flat 'X' where the water gets thinner and becomes again a bit wider while moving in a projectiles trajectory. Could any one please explain.[image]

Comment: the answer by superfast jellyfish in this question is the one you are looking for https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/575582/why-is-the-milk-falling-in-a-spiral-here

Comment: yeah its resolved. Thanks. :)